# Google map for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, google-maps

I have  sql server table,in which one column is Latitude and other column is longitude.I have 950 rows in this table.Now i want to add Google map marker point for all this 950 rows.so totally 950 points.I am using Google map control for ASP.Net for doing this task.For adding a single point in a map, following are the code.

```
GooglePoint GP = new GooglePoint();
GP.Latitude = 43.65669;
GP.Longitude = -79.43270;
GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Points.Add(GP);
```

Now i want to take this lat and long from my sql server table.so that it should add itself all the points in the map.Please help me how to do this.Any example code??
Now i have tried with this code.But i didn't get the point.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Width = "1000px";
        GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Height = "800px";
        GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.MapType = "Hybrid";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=GEOFINY5;Initial Catalog=sample;Integrated Security=True";
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select lat,long from map",con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //int i = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                GooglePoint gp = new GooglePoint();
                //gp.ID = i.ToString;
                gp.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetValue(1));
                gp.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetValue(2));
                gp.InfoHTML = "Hello!!";
                GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Points.Add(gp);
            }
            con.Close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

Note:
     I have used Google Map JavaScript API V3 with fusion tables already.But now i would prefer doing with sql server rather than fusion tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
<iframe align="middle" width="800" height="400" src="http://regiohelden.de/google-maps/map.php?width=800&amp;height=400&amp;hl=de&amp;q=<%#Eval("Hotel_Address") %> <%#Eval("Hotel_City") %>+(<%#Eval("Hotel_Name") %>)&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=16&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

and use this in web.config file

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="googlemaps.subgurim.net" value="ABQIAAAA5b0MiuEiQRYUHB2eaeT5XRRRh87LaJKgnubN7EENjpWM3qNBVhSyngHVcUObtYAlLD3CLsIR0Jd7TA"/>
<add key="localhost.SlideShow" value="http://localhost/maabookings/SlideShow.asmx"/>
</appSettings>
```